# Could not build wheels for libsass

Tags: python, django, docker, sass, wagtail

Hey guys i'm trying to start a project in wagtail using docker and I have the following requeirements

```
Django>=4.2,<5.1
wagtail>=5.2,<5.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
libsass==0.22.0
django-libsass==0.9.0
django-compressor==4.4
wagtail-metadata==5.0.0
wagtail-modeltranslation==0.14
wagtail-orderable==1.2.0
```

and here is my Dockerfile

```
# /app/Dockerfile
# Pull the base image
FROM python:3.11.4-alpine3.17 AS builder

# Set workdirectory
WORKDIR /src/

# Enviroment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install server packages
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev libwebp-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libxml2 \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /tmp/*

# Install python packages
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --upgrade pip setuptools \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Postgres Entrypoint
COPY src/entrypoint.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/src/entrypoint.sh"]

# Copy needed files
COPY src .
```

and the docker docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/src/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.dev
    env_file:
      - infra/dev/env_files/.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:12.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - infra/dev/env_files/.env.dev.db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Here is my project file system if it helps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4sFu.png)

Everytime i run docker-compose up -d --build it returns "Could not build wheels for libsass"

I tried updating pip and other versions of libsass but seems not to work

Here is the full error:

[Full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMOHh.png)

Comment: Please include exact error message for the "can't build wheels". That saves the rest of us having to try to reproduce your system.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I added the image that contains the error,  hope it helps, sorry i wasn't aible to post this earlier had some busy days and had no time to come to my PC, this is a project that I'm using to learn a few things

Answer (score 0):

Typing the error message from your failed compile into Google leads to https://github.com/sass/libsass-python/issues/282

Personally this is why I don't use alpine as my base image. It being super slimmed down is great for building small images - if you have the time to sort out all the dependencies. I would suggest starting from something less stripped down. For example the docker-wagtail-develop repo starts from `python:3.8-bullseye` or bakerydemo uses `FROM python:3.9-slim`.